# How to score the clusters obtained through igraph community detection

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

I have constructed a gene co-expression network from RNA-seq data. The network file is in edge list format of memory around 1gb which was created by calculating Pearson correlation of each gene pairs and the gene pairs which having correlation >95% were selected to create the edge list.

I have clustered this gene network (edge list) using igraph R package "cluster_louvian" community detection algorithm and obtained 534 subclusters. Many of the subclusters have only one vertex in it

How can I score the clusters in order to identify the best clusters which has more vertexes and edges and important for further studies.

Comment: please add you code as a n mcve.

Comment: did you first check if the graph is connected?  if not, that may explain why you have so many singleton clusters. and the definition of "best" usually depends on what you want to do afterwards.  are you trying to compare with a known classification (say by cancer type) or are you attempting to find clusters that have over expression with respect to the Gene Ontology?  or do you have some other analysis in mind?

Comment: Yes, my network is a discontinous network which has isolated nodes and nodes with degree = 1. I am trying to find clusters that have over expression with respect to gene ontology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide any data, so I will illustrate with an arbitrary example.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(20,0.1)
plot(g)

CL = cluster_louvain(g)
plot(g, vertex.color=CL$membership)
```

[image: Example graph]

Now you can get the number of vertices in each cluster and the number of edges that connect them.

```
## number of vertices per cluster
table(CL$membership)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 1 3 2 3 5 5

## number of edges within each cluster
NumClust = max(CL$membership)
sapply(1:NumClust, function(i)
    ecount(induced_subgraph(g, which(CL$membership==i))))
[1] 0 0 2 1 2 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you sir. In cytoscape network visualizer, the various clustering tools provide scoring system to the cluster obtained. Same way I wanted to know whether we can score clusters developed through community detection algorithms.